# Несколько фильтров в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю приложение на React. Получаю массив объектов из api. Возникла проблема в фильтрации. Нужно сделать поиск по категории и цене. Цену вводим в инпуты. Не понимаю как сделать чтобы совместно с фильтрацией по категории можно было сделать фильтрацию по цене.
Вот примерный вид массива, получаемого из api, который находится в state:

```
state = {
    data: [],
    category: 'all',
    priceStart: '',
    priceEnd: ''
}
data = [
   {name: 'First Name', category: 'cat', price: '17262'},
   {name: 'Second Name', category: 'bird', price: '7562'}, 
   {name: 'Third Name', category: 'dog', price: '28412'}, 
]
```

Написал функцию, которая меняет состояния в зависимости от вводимых данных:

```
chFilter =  (type, val) => {
    switch(type) {
        case 'category':
            this.setState({ category: val });
            break;
        case 'priceStart':
            this.setState({ priceStart: val });
            break;
        case 'priceEnd':
            this.setState({ priceEnd: val });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Куда дальше двигаться не понимаю. Сейчас работает фильтр по категории:

```
filter(items, filter){
    switch(filter){
        case 'all':
            return items;
        case 'auto':
            return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'auto');
        case 'immovable':
            return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'immovable');
        case 'cameras':
            return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'cameras');
        case 'laptops':
            return items.filter((e) => e.category === 'laptops');
        default:
            return items;
    }
}
```

Соответственно отображаем следующие данные:

```
const visible = this.filter(data, category)

<div className='category d-flex'>
  <h5>По категории</h5>
  <select 
   id = 'category'
   value = {filter}
   onChange = { (event) =>  chFilter('category', event.target.value) }>
                            { option }
  </select>
 </div>
 <div className="price-filter d-flex">
   <div className="input-group ">
     <h5>По цене</h5>
     <input type="number" placeholder='с' value = { priceStart } onChange = { (event) =>  chFilter('priceStart', event.target.value) }/>
     <input type="number" placeholder='до' value = { priceEnd } onChange = { (event) =>  chFilter('priceEnd', event.target.value) } />
    <div className="input-group-append">
     <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: а где ваш `JSX` код?

Comment: Добавил JSX, думал что нет особой необходимости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам что-то такое нужно:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: [
      { name: "First Name", category: "cat", price: "17262" },
      { name: "Second Name", category: "bird", price: "7562" },
      { name: "Third Name", category: "dog", price: "28412" }
    ],
    category: "all",
    priceStart: "",
    priceEnd: ""
  });
  function handleChange({ target: { name, value } }) {
    setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  }
  let data = state.data;
  if (state.category && state.category !== 'all') {
    data = data.filter(d => d.category === state.category);
  }
  if (state.priceStart) {
    data = data.filter(d => Number(d.price) >= Number(state.priceStart));
  }
  if (state.priceEnd) {
    data = data.filter(d => Number(d.price) <= Number(state.priceEnd));
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((d, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          {d.name} {d.category} {d.price}
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="category d-flex">
        <h5>По категории</h5>
        <select
          id="category"
          name="category"
          value={state.category}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
        <option>all</option>
        {state.data.map((d, i) => <option key={i}>{d.category}</option>)}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="price-filter d-flex">
        <div className="input-group ">
          <h5>По цене</h5>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="с"
            value={state.priceStart}
            name="priceStart"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="до"
            value={state.priceEnd}
            name="priceEnd"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <div className="input-group-append">
            <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
              Button
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit youthful-sinoussi-wk4gj]